# How to do pagination of JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, pagination, getjson

I want to show 3 records in one page, and click next button to see another 3 records.
I try to use jquery plugin easyPaginate to test this, but it is not working.

#### My HTML

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "json.json";
        $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
           var id = field.id;
           var name = field.name;
           var category = field.category;
             $("#show_data").append("<li class='item'>"+"<div>"+ id +"</div>"+  "<p>"+  name +"</p>" +"<p>" +  category +"</p></li>");
        });
    });
});</script><body><ul id="easyPaginate"><div id="show_data"></div><ul></body>


<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.snippet.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easyPaginate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

My Script file

```
$(function() {
$('#easyPaginate').easyPaginate({
    paginateElement: 'li',
    elementsPerPage: 3,
});  });
```

MY Json.json file

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Mary",
    "sex": "F"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Peter",
    "sex": "M"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Ben",
    "sex": "M"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Sam",
    "sex": "M"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "April",
    "sex": "F"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Benson",
    "sex": "M"
}]
```

Comment: `but it is not work` - the solution would be to "make it work" ... hope that is as helpful as your description of the problem - one thing I did notice ... there is no element with `id="easyPaginate"` in your HTML ... so `$('#easyPaginate')` wont find anything to work with - check the [easyPaginate documentation](http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/) for examples of how to use *easyPaginate* - perhaps you meant `$('#show_data').easyPaginate ...`

Comment: Thx your comment, I edit it, but still not work, but it is work in  <ul id="easyPaginate">
     <li>AAAAA</li>
     <li>BBBBB</li>
     <li>CCCCC</li>
     <li>DDDDD</li>
     <li>EEEEE</li>
     <li>FFFFF</li>
     <li>GGGGG</li>
     <li>HHHHH</li>
     <li>IIIII</li>
     <li>JJJJJ</li>
     <li>FFFFF</li>
     <li>GGGGG</li>
     <li>HHHHH</li>
    </ul>

Comment: `I edit it` - what did you edit? `but still not work` - then you have to find the problem - I would recommend using the browsers Developer Tools, look for errors in the console, use inspector to see what is happening with the DOM etc etc - basic debugging stuff

Comment: Why paginate at all?  Browsers have scroll bars, and if all your data is available when the page loads anyway, why not let the user scroll?